# Where would a question about paper-and-pencil games (such as tic-tac-toe) be on-topic?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where would a question about a "made-up" paper game be on-topic?

**Examples:**

- Tic-tac-toe
- Dots and boxes
- Sudoku (maybe?)

[Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com) is strictly *video* games, and [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com) is for *board* (and card) games.  Where would these games land?

Comment: I thought you were talking about games involving Ol' Scratch, and came here to recommend [christianity.se]. Have you investigated [puzzling.se]?

Comment: Depending on what your question is, it might be on-topic on [math.SE].

Comment: @ArthurFischer Possibly, but Puzzling appears to be the best choice here.

Comment: [Role-Playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) also exists, but these games obviously don't fit into that category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [Puzzling](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com) is probably the answer. I see the following tags there:

- [tic-tac-toe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tic-tac-toe) *6 questions*
- [sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sudoku) *35 questions*
- [dots-and-boxes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dots-and-boxes) *2 questions*

More importantly, the tags have tag descriptions, so they're not just fly-by-night additions that were otherwise missed.